# Use array string as array key

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, foreach

I have an array. after `print_r($arr)` as below:

```
Array ( 
  [0] => Array ( 
      [groupid] => 5 
      [radminid] => 1 
      [type] => system 
      [system] => private 
  ) 
  [1] => Array ( 
      [groupid] => 10 
      [radminid] => 2 
      [type] => system 
      [system] => private 
  )
)
```

I would like to change the array `key` to `groupid`, something like `$arr[$arr[groupid]]` and I tried

```
foreach($array as $key => $value){
    $arr[$value] = $arr[$arr['groupid']];
}
```

How to use the `$arr[groupid]` as `$arr` key? below is what I need.

```
Array ( 
  [5] => Array ( 
      [groupid] => 5 
      [radminid] => 1 
      [type] => system 
      [system] => private 
  ) 
  [10] => Array ( 
      [groupid] => 10 
      [radminid] => 2 
      [type] => system 
      [system] => private 
  )
)
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use

```
$array = array_column($array, null, 'groupid');
```

[array_column](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php) — Return the values from a single column in the input array

> **Note:**
>   **column_key** The column of values to return. This value may be
>   an integer key of the column you wish to retrieve, or it may be a
>   string key name for an associative array or property name. It may also
>   be **NULL** to return complete arrays or objects (this is useful together
>   with **index_key** to reindex the array).

*In case you don't have the support of array_column. Please see [link](https://github.com/ramsey/array_column/blob/master/src/array_column.php).*

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/N3PbH)

**Output**

```
Array
(
    [5] => Array
        (
            [groupid] => 5
            [radminid] => 1
            [type] => system
            [system] => private
        )

    [10] => Array
        (
            [groupid] => 10
            [radminid] => 2
            [type] => system
            [system] => private
        )

)
```

Comment: Hi, my php version is 5.2.8, feel doesn't support array_column.. is it any other solution for lower version

Comment: you are so nice.

Answer (score 1):

You only need to iterate through your array and replace your key with your wanted key.

```
$newArray = array();
for($i=0;$i<count($array);$i++){
    $newArray[$array[$i]['groupid']] = $array[$i];
}
var_dump($array);
```

Comment: since my php version < 5.5, and this is suitable for me, but I don't know why, if using `$i<count($array)`, just equal to 10, but actual in array have 20

Comment: Should not happend at all see the offical doc https://www.php.net/manual/de/function.count.php

Answer (score 1):

[array_column](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php) is what you are looking for,

`$array = array_column($array,null,"groupid");`

Answer (score 0):

Use `array_walk`

```
 array_walk($a, function($v) use(&$r){$r[$v['groupid']] = $v;});
```

Working example : https://3v4l.org/rB0UT

Answer (score 0):

You may use [array_reduce](https://www.php.net/array_reduce) for this kind of operations ([sandbox](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/1f93ea0c34c2199478cdbb1e5b027d417d89865d)):

```php
$array = array_reduce($array, function ($accu, $curr) {
    $accu[$curr['groupid']] = $curr;
    return $accu;
}, []);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [5] => Array
        (
            [groupid] => 5
            [radminid] => 1
            [type] => system
            [system] => private
        )

    [10] => Array
        (
            [groupid] => 10
            [radminid] => 2
            [type] => system
            [system] => private
        )

)
```

Comment: That might work, but it doesn’t make the most sense … purpose of that function is to reduce the array to a _single_ value. Using array_walk as suggested in a different answer makes much more sense, logically.